# python.el for long time python-mode.el user?

Tags: emacs, python

Are there loveshack python-mode (python.el) equivalents of

- py-shell
- py-execute-region
- py-execute-class-or-def

that are available in python-mode.el?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not that familiar with either, but maybe these are equivalent:

python-send-region

```
Send the region to the inferior Python process.
May print a message, so only suitable for interactive use.
```

python-send-region-and-go

```
Send the region to the inferior Python process.
Then switch to the process buffer.
```

python-send-defun

```
Send the current defun (class or method) to the inferior Python process.
```

python-python-command

```
Shell command to run Python interpreter.
Any arguments can't contain whitespace.
Note that IPython may not work properly;
it must at least be used with the `-cl' flag,
i.e. use `ipython -cl'.
Doesn't take full effect unless set through Custom.
```

Also check out 'gallina' python.el as mentioned [here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ProgrammingWithPythonDotEl).

Answer (score 0):

All commands mentioned here are from python-mode.el. Loading shipped python.el does not unload them, nor does python-mode.el unload python.el commands. With one exception: as for major-mode, latest loaded will prevail and set its lighter.